# Simpler syntax to bind some parameters to a template template paramater

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

A class `ExpectTTs` takes a number of template template parameters:

```
template< template<typename> class... TT >
struct ExpectTTs {};
```

Another type requires two template parameters. I need to fix one and pass the rest to `ExpectTTs`.

Currently I'm using this solution:

```
template< typename T >
struct TwoTs {
    template< typename U >
    struct Inner {};
};

ExpectTTs< TwoTs<int>::Inner >
```

Is it possible to change something so that I can pass a simple template instantiation like `TwoTs<int>` to `ExpectTTs`?

In several points in my codebase I have expressions like `ExpectTTs< A, B, C<int>::Inner, D, E<int,int>::Inner, F<void>::Inner >` and it seems unnecessary hard to read and write.

Any C++ version is fine.

Comment: It's hard to answer this kind of question without understanding what you goal is. How is this used? A template template parameter, and a type is two different things, but you seem to want to be able to pass a pack of both mixed?

Comment: I have a class hierarchy that uses static polymorphism. Child classes pass their parents their own type plus template template parameters; these implement some members and functions.
My goal is to always pass template template parameters, but I'm looking for a nicer syntax to bind some types to the template template parameters.

Comment: What about using template aliases? `template <typename T> using TwoTsInt = TwoTs<int, T>;`

Comment: its not quite clear what can change and what not. "Is it possible to change something so that I can pass a simple template instantiation...." sure but you'd need to change `ExpectTTs` because currently it takes template template parameters and if I understand correctly you want to pass a type

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: `ExpectTTs` needs to work with templates. But yes, I would like to pass it both templates and types that have a template member. I'm wondering if there's any way to implement that.

Comment: can you show an example of what you would like to write instead of `ExpectTTs< A, B, C<int>::Inner, D, E<int,int>::Inner, F<void>::Inner >` ?

Comment: @super: it would work, but it requires one extra declaration for every time I want to bind a type to a template. I don't think I would prefer it to the current situation.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: ideally `ExpectTTs< A, B, C<int>, D, E<int,int>, F<void> >`. It's so so much easier to read and write.

Comment: @Helloer I don't think there is really any way around that. You could use something like `GenericPartial<TwoTs, int>::Inner` to avoid having to create an `Inner` in each separate class, but it wouldn't improve the syntax in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a template taking two parameters you cannot only specify one and obtain a template template. That is simply not possible. You also cannot create a template template alias as you can create a template alias with `using`. C++ does not make it easy to work with template templates, you can basically only use them when you fully instantiate them or when you pass them as a parameter to a template.

You also cannot get `ExpectTTs` really working with both template template parameters and type template parameters, since C++ strictly distinguishes between them (otherwise you could do something like let `ExpectTTs` extract the inner type). *Maybe* you could let `ExpectTTs` only take type template parameters, and make also `A`, `B`, and `D` have an `Inner` template while themselves being types, so you can let `ExpectTTs` always do the work for extracting the `Inner`s. But then of course, you wouldn't be able to pass STL-templates like `std::optional` directly.

One small thing you could (in my opinion) improve in your design is using something like this:

```
#include <utility>  // For the example
#include <optional>

template<template<class> class...>
struct ExpectTTs {};

template<template<class...> class TT, class T>
struct bind {
    template<class U>
    using bound_t = TT<T, U>;
};

ExpectTTs<std::optional, bind<std::pair, int>::bound_t> e{};
```

It's maybe even more verbose, but it does not need the intrusive `Inner` type and returns exactly the template template you want and not some other stand-in.